# Is sending an object created via intent.getSerializableExtra to handler.postDelayed leading to Code Execution?

Tags: penetration-test, android

I'm new to android pentesting and I would like to know :

if sending an object created via the result of `intent.getSerializableExtra("EXTRA_TEST");`

to `handler.postDelayed(TheObject,500)` could lead to a vulnerability ?

like

```
d.a aObject = (d.a) intent.getSerializableExtra("EXTRA_BUY_TAB_START_POSITION_EXPLORE");
if (aVar2 != null) {
    this.handler.postDelayed(new e(aVar2), 500);
}
```

I imagine that if we send an intent with a serialized runnable the target application would execute the malicious code...
Is it right ?

edit : 
"d" is  : public final class d extends Fragment 
and d.a is

```
public static final class a {
        private a() {
        }

        public /* synthetic */ a(DefaultConstructorMarker defaultConstructorMarker) {
            this();
        }

        public final d a() {
            return new d();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is some automatically decompiled code because it's horrendous to read.

Since the Runnable object is retrieved from a key/value map (the intent object) you could force a custom runnable into the intent map at the specific key "EXTRA_BUY_TAB_START_POSITION_EXPLORE" so that it would be run after 500ms.

In you code you need to clarify :

- What is aVar2 ?
- What does the class "e" do ?
- Your d.a object is never used in your sample

I hope that will lead you to the correct path.

Comment: Oh sorry I badly renamed aVar2 the d.a is : d.a aVar2 = ... and not aObject
The e class is just an interface (https://pastebin.com/p3VFG8dS)

Comment: I'm trying to create a payload but I get the error :  
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered ClassNotFoundException reading a Serializable object (name = fr.neolexsecurity.rceapp.a)` Do you know How should I do that ?